# How to install Brave Web Browser for ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I'm having trouble installing Brave Web Browser for ubuntu 18.04 for desktop.  I've tried the instructions on GitHub and the instructions for ubuntu 16.04 listed in FAQ, but still doesn't work. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the [official way](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux) doesn't work, open Terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and run-

```
sudo snap install brave
```

It'll install the community maintained unofficial version.

Comment: Update: The community maintained snap isn't available anymore. Install it the official way.